# Reshape numpy (a, b, c) shape array into (a, object)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a **list** `outer_list` containing 3D **lists**. Each **inner list** has shape `(a, ?, c)` where `?` is a variable number. Below is an example of what `outer_list` might look like.

```
# In this case `a=2` and `c=3`
outer_list = [
    [
        [[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 7]],
        [[7, 8, 9], [11, 15, 17]] # ?=2
    ],
    [
        [[5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 4]],
        [[1, 6, 3], [3, 6, 4], [34, 2, 1]] # ?=3
    ],
    [
        [[1, 2, 3]],
        [[5, 4, 7]] # ?=1
    ]
]
```

I want to save this list as a .npy file and so need to convert this into a numpy array.

1. So far I've tried to convert **each** inner list into an numpy array with the following code `np.array(inner_list, dtype="object")`.
2. This leaves me with a list of numpy arrays. I then try to convert this list with `np.array(outer_list, dtype="object")` but I get a `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (a, 1, c) into shape (a,)`.
3. Turns out that for some reason on step 1, if the `inner_list` is of shape `(a, 1, c`), like the third entry in the example above, instead of becoming shape `(a,)` when I convert it to a numpy array using `np.array(inner_list, dtype="object")`, it becomes shape `(a, 1, c)`.
4. So I have a list of numpy arrays either of shape `(a, )` or shape `(a, 1, c)` and I'm unable to turn this list into a numpy array.

Is there anyway I can turn a `(a, 1, c)` numpy array into shape `(a, )`?

Comment: "I want to save this list as a .npy file" Why? If it's not a valid np.array what's the point of using numpy? Use pickle instead?

Comment: "Is there anyway I can turn a (a, 1, c) numpy array into shape (a, )?" Yes just use for example np.ravel. But I'm pretty sure you are attacking this the wrong way...

Comment: Hi yes thanks for suggesting `pickle`. I had only vaguely heard of that before and turns out it achieves exactly what I want. Thanks again!

Comment: Using `np.array([alist_of_arrays])` does not give you good control.  If the arrays all have the same shape, the result is a multidimensional numeric array.  If they differ in shape, you either get a "ragged" warning and object dtype array, or an error.  The error results when the arrays differ in trailing dimensions.  To have full control over creating an object dtype array, you have to initial one with the desired shape and dtype, and then assign the elements - one at a time, or with some sort of list assignment.